# Configure Windows Server Performance Monitor to create new log for every day

Tags: windows, performance-monitoring

I want to config my "Data Collector Set" to create a new log file each day instead of appending logs from this day to existing log file. I configured the schedule to run every day at specific time, and also started it manually but it does not create new log for each new day.

Comment: Toward the second half of this article from David Klee, there are instructions on how to setup a rolling window of reports that don't require any extra tasks or scripts to remove/cleanup the perfmon reports: https://www.davidklee.net/articles/sql-server-articles/perfmon/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have onr file per day, you can do like this. On my server I store on file per day during 7 days. It deletes the oldest files.

In the properties of yours performances counters :
[image]

You can prefix the name of your file and select his format like this example.

And in the properties of your collector, you must select Restart the data set (sorry my interface is in french, you can see the image below) and select the 
duration of the task :
[image]

To delete the oldest logs, you can go the Task tab and create a job for that. It's the default paramters of Windows :

After all, you mus restart yours counters to apply yours modifications.

good luck!
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sorcha so my schedule configs are correct and I only need t set Stop Condition? Also after setting all things, should I start in manually ?

Comment: yes you are right, You need stop conditions and select the option 'restart collector set'. After, Restart yours counters

Answer (score -1):

for new windows.
please check this video: https://youtu.be/eG-bEd9TNzs

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue. And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/509702)